# US forum/site with opinions on suburbs

Tags: usa, housing

Is there some US site where I could read peoples opinions about suburbs/towns?

I've used Trulia neighborhood info to get some useful statistics, but it's very impersonal and only measures handful of metrics.

I'm particularly interested in SF Bay Area.

Answer (score 2):

http://www.city-data.com/forum/ - you can get responses from people living there.

For SF, http://www.city-data.com/forum/san-francisco-oakland/